# Ubuntu startup USB doesn't boot after I partitioned the hard disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have an old pc with a Core 2 Dou CPU, and respective motherboard and BIOS, and a SATA2 hard disk. The Ubuntu startup USB which I created using Startup Disk Creator, boots only in two conditions:

1. If the hard disk is not connected.
2. If the hard disk is connected but not partitioned.

But after I partitioned and formatted the hard disk using GParted, of course only the first option is available which doesn't let me install Ubuntu on the hard disk from the USB. The partition table is GPT and all partitions are ext4.

Comment: You've provided no release details, clues as to which installer you're using (different ISOs use different installers but you've not been specific as to release or desktop/server/flavor you're using, if a main or alternate ISO was used etc). Did you verify ISO? and then verify the write to your USB media? (this step varies on the *unstated* release used)

Comment: If using gpt with old BIOS, you need a tiny 1MB unformatted partition with the bios_grub flag. I booted Ubuntu that way until I got a newer UEFI based system. Since I thought I might move some drives to UEFI system, I typically added both an ESP - efi system partition and bios_grub as first two partitions. Then only a reinstall of grub was required to convert a BIOS boot system to UEFI boot.